# writing a console program to test my wcf service in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, service

Hi i need to write a console program to test a web service that i have, any idea how to do that? and where do i place the codes?

Comment: You're not very clear on what the **problem** is - you don't know how to create a console app? You don't know how to import a service refernence? Or what else is the problem......

Comment: i don't knw hw to create a console app i don't think i knw hw to import a service reference either...

Comment: do you want to test if that webservice is working or not , if so use microsoft..existing utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use wcf storm, google it and download

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Create a new console app: `File > New Project > in the Windows tab > Console app`

[image]

Step 2: add a service reference to your service: in Solution Explorer, right-click on `References > Add Service Reference` and add your service

[image]

[image]

Step 3: code your calls to the service and test your service

So which part is not clear to you?

Comment: Hi so i created a console application, now how do i call the service?

Comment: @GJJ: when you did an `Add Service Reference` you should have gotten a class for your service - instantiate the `(yourservicename)Client` class and call methods on it

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create console for that, you just need to open the application the is created for that. See your WcfTestClient.Exe located most probably at:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

Or, if you insist to have a different test approach eg: Parallel or Stress call, you can just create new Console App and add a service reference to your project and it should be available to you by then.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write , its already availble

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee383989.aspx